# FractionRes.class Error Android

Tags: android

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/FractionRes.class

[image]

Comment: share your `build.gradle`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you are  declaring `play-services:8.1.0` twice. The second time you do exclude the `support-v4.jar` however it is finally included from the first time:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

So, keep only one declaration of `play-services` in your `gradle` and put all exclusions in this one

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```